# Unexpected results using Excel Data Reader

Tags: c#, excel, parsing, file-upload

I'm reading an XLSX (Microsoft Excel XML file) using the Excel Data Reader from http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/ and I getting some unexpected results.

The following code outputs data from multiple tabs

```
var reader = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(uploadFile.InputStream);
while (reader.Read())
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(reader.FieldCount );
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(reader[i] + "*");
    }
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n~\n");
}
```

On a single line, I can get data from 3 or more tabs.

I would expect this to loop through and show all of the contents of the first tab and only the first tab.

What am I missing?

Update:  It appears that the above code does work fine if there is only 1 tab in the excel file.   This may just be a bug with this library.   Has anyone else used this library to parse excel files with multiple tabs?

Thanks

Comment: Also an unexpected result is when we try to read an excel with values that use comma (,) as decimal point. It converts 3,5 to 35. :-O

Answer (score 2):

OK, so my reply is extremely late with reference to this question, but if its any help try encapsulating your code in a `reader.NextResult()` block. This works the same way as when you parse through multiple DataTable objects within a DataSet.

Additionally, this approach has a very small memory footprint as opposed to the `reader.AsDataSet()` method, which hogs a lot of memory even for workbooks as small as 20MBs

eg

```
var reader = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(uploadFile.InputStream);
do
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(reader.FieldCount );
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(reader[i] + "*");
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n~\n");
    }
}while(reader.NextResult());
```

Answer (score -1):

Which is why I am using [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/). I have tried several other Excel readers, this one actually worked for me.